# Adding table of certain attributes to map layout?

Tags: arcpy, attribute-table, table, layouts

I am using ArcMap 10.2 and I'm looking for a way to add  a table containing certain fields from select elements from a featureclass to my map. Ive tried the add table option from the attribute table, but it doesn't quite give what I want (the table must be editable to look a certain way).

Are there any options out there for 10.2 like arcpy.mapping.tableview or will upgrading to 10.3 so I can get access to the "graphic table element" function be best?

Comment: The most common technique is to clone graphic and text elements but I'm not sure which version made that available.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an **excel object** via the **insert menu** and style accordingly. That's after exporting table data for the selected features to dBASE or other format readable in excel.

[image]